# Old imagery WMTS

Tags: data, tiles, imagery, wmts, aerial-photography

I am looking for a web imagery tile service (WMTS)  that provides old imagery, in the same vein as Google Earth's old imagery, but one that could be integrated into an OpenLayers or Leaflet map.

Any idea?

Comment: Globally or a specific country, region, state or city?

Comment: Ideally globally!

Answer (score 1):

[Terra Server](https://www.terraserver.com) deals in "old" satellite imagery.  Just enter address or latLon and choose what epoch you would like to view.